# Scapy NativeCANSocket throws OSError:Invalid Argument for a packet with 2000 bytes of payload

Tags: sockets, scapy, can-bus

I tried implementing my own CAN protocol in Scapy and added a flag in the NativeCANSocket to accommodate the new protocol.

Setup : Oracle VM Virtualbox with Linux kernel 6.5.5

Protocol definition in : scapy/layers/can.py

Modification in Native CANSocket init function : Addition of protocol flag with default value false. Can be set to true while creating the instance of CANSocket.

```
load_layer('can')
load_contrib('cansocket)   #NativeCANsocket by default
pkt = My_Protocol(id = 123, length = 20, data = '12345678')
sock_p = CANSocket(channel = 'vcan0', protocol_flag = True)
sock_p.send(pkt)   --------> *OS error : [Errno22] Invalid Argument*
```

*error points to supersocket.py --> return self.outs.send(sx)*

Expected output : packet is sent and the number of bytes sent is returned.

I tried the same steps with CANFD packet and it was successful and as a result, 72 was returned.
I then changed the CANFD MTU from 64 to 2000 bytes and then the sent operation failed which makes me believe that this is a maximum size problem.
But I am not familiar with Socket programming so I do not know if there is a limitation of size in send() or if it is a different problem.